# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token U error in android app built in appcelerator

Tags: android, mysql, appcelerator

I build an quiz app in appcelerator, that is getting questions from mysql database and it seems whenever I update the database with new category of question, get this error. If rebuild the app and install it on phone again, the problem is gone. The app is pretty big now so I don't even know where to look to find out what causes this error. I would much appreciate any ideas.
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Maybe you should explain how you update the questions, and read http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: You can search for this error **select * from question where cat_id** in your whole project by using Studio search tool. Only then you can find the error easily and I think this error is just a typo error.

Comment: Yeah you were right, it was a typo. There should have been  - <b> instead of -<b> (with no spaces), dont know how that happened though.